# How can I fix broken URLs after migration

Tags: migration

I copied my staged working EE site to a SiteGround production server and the URLs are now broken. 
I have the site in xyznew directory.
- The homepage does come up and displays properly at www.xyz.org/xyznew
- But when I hover over all the top level menu items, my browser shows the links as www.xyz.org/xyznew/#  which just returns back to the current page, the homepage. 
- When I hover over all my second level menu items, they return links of the form xyznew//events/julyevent   [Yes with double slashes and not prefixed with the domain name. )

It seems like a configuration file issues, but I don't know what setting(s) are off.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant template code for how your links are generated so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this question closed. I've turned the site migration over to a more experienced EE developer than me.